# In MS word findall (Find in Main Document) is very slow for long documents so how to use macro to achive the same by looping one find at a time

Tags: vba, ms-word, find

In MS word findall (Find in Main Document) is very slow for long documents

The advantage of findall is that it selects all the found words (i.e  highlighted in light transparent blue), then i can change the font or any other properties in one go.

But the problem is when the document is very very big (in my case) find all takes lot of time or it hangs. I can say i dont know what is happening in the backgground

So i have decided to use a macro by find one word and loop through the find till the last occurence of the word and store the selections in the background and in the end display all the selections.

So is it possible.

In Microsoft word i can find a word once as follows:

[image]

And the following macro is same as this:

```
Sub findawordonce()
'
' Macro6 Macro
'
'
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "PQXY"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
End Sub
```

When i find a word (eg:word1) using findNext it selects an occurence of the word which is represented by hightlighting the word by default in transparent blue color

**What i observe is:**

When i use FindNext again, the next occurence of the word is selected and selection on the previous occurence is gone.

**What i want is:**

When i use FindNext again, the next occurence of the word is selected  retaining the previous selection.

This is not possible with the UI, but is it possible with the macro.

I want the macro to find a word which is selected and loop again and find another word and keep accumulating the selections.

I know in word we can find a word in the entire document. But my document is very very big and many times it hangs up.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use Find/Replace if, for example, you want to apply the same font or other properties? Find/Replace can also work with standard formatting... It's not possible to save *selections* to an array - there can be only one selection in a document. A user can make a single, discontiguous selection by using the CTRL key, but VBA is not able to do this. It's only possible to store *ranges* in an array. But I'm fairly certain Find/Replace is going to be much faster than using Find to assign Range objects to an array, then looping that array after-the-fact.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store multiple selections in Array and later do select all the selections in the Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54881150/store-multiple-selections-in-array-and-later-do-select-all-the-selections-in-the)

Comment: Indeed, it *is* a duplicate! Moreover, the OP has apparently ignored the advice given in the other thread regarding the triviality of the task using Find/Replace...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this an feedback?

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'Updated by Extendoffice 20180625
Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog, GetStr(1 To 100) As String '100 files is the maximum applying this code
Dim xFindStr As String
Dim xReplaceStr As String
Dim xDoc As Document
On Error Resume Next
Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With xFileDialog
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "All WORD File ", "*.docx", 1
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    i = 1
    If .Show = -1 Then
        For Each stiSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
            GetStr(i) = stiSelectedItem
            i = i + 1
        Next
        i = i - 1
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    xFindStr = InputBox("Find what:", "hall", xFindStr)
    xReplaceStr = InputBox("Replace with:", "NOTHING", xReplaceStr)
    For j = 1 To i Step 1
        Set xDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=GetStr(j), Visible:=True)
        Windows(GetStr(j)).Activate
        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = xFindStr  'Find What
            .Replacement.Text = xReplaceStr  'Replace With
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindAsk
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchByte = True
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        Application.Run macroname:="NEWMACROS"
        ActiveDocument.Save
        ActiveWindow.Close
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End With
MsgBox "Operation end, please view", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: can you explain a bit the macro. Also where to put my filename and the string i am looking for to search

Comment: You save the word file in the folder where you run it.  Is that NOT what you want?

Comment: I will open the file and then do findall. So i will not need any things regarding opening of file or saving it. I want to select "PQXY" in my word file which occurs at multiple places (more than 6000 times) all at a once using macro

Comment: `With xFileDialog` I dont have to open my file using macro