# Store multiple selections in Array and later do select all the selections in the Array

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to find a word and save the selection in an array and then find again and then save the next selection in the array. And in the end try to select all the selections in the array.

I am trying this but its with half knowledge. I am not able to get it. Can some one help.

```
Sub Macro6()
'
' Macro6 Macro
'
'
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
Dim selecttest(2) As Selection
For I = 1 To 2
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "PQXY"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    Set selecttest(I) = Selection
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Next I
For I = 1 To 2
  selecttest(I).Select
Next I
End Sub
```

I want to keep the selection in the loop and show them in the end.

Solution i tried:

```
Sub Macro61()
'
' Macro6 Macro
'
'
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
Dim selecttest(2) As Range
For i = 1 To 2
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "PQXY"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    Set selecttest(i) = Selection.Range
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Next i

For i = 1 To 2
selecttest(i).Select
Next i
End Sub
```

Problem above is selecttest(2) is only selected. I want the end result with both selecttest(1) and selecttest(2) selected

I also tried

```
Dim totalselect as Range
For i = 1 to 2
set totalselect = totalselect + selectest(i)
Next i

totalselect.select
```

It shows error that "+" (plus) operation does not exist

**Solution: Not Possible**

*Found some articles regarding discontinous range selections is not possible by VBA whereas its possible by FindAll*

Find All in VBA: https://forums.windowssecrets.com/showthread.php/124485-Find-All-in-VBA

Reason 1: which talks about findall

> Unfortunately, Microsoft omitted to add support for "Find All" in the
>   VBA object model for Word. In other words, Find All cannot be executed
>   from a macro.
>
> You can loop through all occurrences of the search text in VBA, but
>   that's not the same as Find All.

Reason 2: findall is inderectly related to discontiguous selections which is not possible

> Probably the reason a Find All isn't in VBA is that VBA also has never
>   had any way to deal with discontiguous selections (the kind you can
>   make with Ctrl and the mouse), which is what Find All would produce.
>   The KB article here explains the few things that can be done. Every
>   version since 2002 (including 2010) has made no changes in this area.

Reason 3: computationally expensive, in terms of both processing and memory. if done by VBA

> I suspect this omission was intentional and carefully considered. In
>   the visual context of an open document window, Find All is a perfectly
>   sensible concept. However, in the procedural world of VBA, it is a tad
>   more difficult to work with sets of things, and, often,
>   computationally less efficient.
>
> This isn't to say that it can't be done in VBA, only that I can
>   understand why it wasn't done. For what it's worth, the same is true
>   of the Find object in Excel, with which I have much more intimate, and
>   recent, experience.
>
> To support Find All in VBA would require the Execute method to return
>   a collection of Range objects, which could be computationally
>   expensive, in terms of both processing and memory

Answer (score 0):

Try with two simple changes replacing `Selection` into `Range` object:

```
Sub Macro6()
    ...
    ...
    Dim selecttest(2) As Range 'not Selection
    ...
    ...
    Set selecttest(i) = Selection.Range 'not just a Selection
    ...
End sub
```

Comment: I tried this. But i am not able to show all the selections at a time.

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi, by default you can't do that. Object model doesn't support such operation.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is show the matches, you only need:

```
ActiveDocument.Range.Find.HitHighlight FindText:="PQXY"
```

Comment: No, my goal is to show by VBA. Because i have 6000+ PQXY occurences and many times it hangs.

Comment: VBA cannot select dis-contiguous ranges - only one range can be selected at a time. You need to better explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: In my case i have 6000 PQXY, When i do Findin (Main Document) then word shows  its finding. Since it takes a lot of time and inbetween i want to stop the search, i hit esc (escape) button. then it will show some 2000 PQXY's selected. So word is finding PQXY and adding to selection set, which should also be possible by vba macro

Comment: The main problem in Findall in such big case is it does not show any progress. Sometimes we dont know whats happening

Comment: What is the reason for you wanting to select all these items. If we know this reason we might be able to suggest a better way to get to your goal.

Comment: I want to select all PQXY and change their font. But i have 6000 PQXY in my document

Comment: You can do that with a simple Find/Replace - you don't need a macro for something so trivial.

Comment: But i found we can't change the heading level using Find/Replace (Like level1, Level2 etc.

Comment: That, too, is a trivial undertaking. Evidently you haven't really tried... Again, you don't need a macro!

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim oRng As Word.Range
Set oRng = Selection.Range
oRng.Find.ClearFormatting
With oRng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "shhada"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
         While .Execute
               oRng.Editors.Add wdEditorEveryone
         Wend
         ActiveDocument.SelectAllEditableRanges wdEditorEveryone
         ActiveDocument.DeleteAllEditableRanges wdEditorEveryone
    End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: codes only doesn't question please add some explanation

Comment: This code will limit the search text to all locations within the current document